# Azure Storage: File Metadata

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I am creating a webjob app to periodically (scheduled) read an azure file share and process files. I am using the C# ApI examples provided but cannot figure out how to get file metadata with my directory listing. I would like to do something as simple as sort files by modified date.  Does anyone have an example of fetching metadata with the Listing Files.

```
 FileResultSegment resultSegment = await share.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmentedAsync(token);
 results.AddRange(resultSegment.Results);
```

Results in no **MetaData** or **Properties** defined for the IListFileItem below.

```
foreach (IListFileItem listItem in results)
            {
                // listItem type will be CloudFile or CloudFileDirectory
                Console.WriteLine("- {0} (type: {1})", listItem.Uri, listItem.GetType());
            }
```

Comment: FYI: If you use the segmented listing methods you need to follow the continuation tokens or you won't get a full result list. If you don't want to follow continuation tokens manually, use the ListFilesAndDirectories method rather than the segmented version which will return an iterator to lazily grab results for you.

Answer (score 1):

What about casting your results ?

```
foreach (var item in results)
{
    if (item is CloudFile)
    {
        var cloudFile = (CloudFile) item;

        // You can now access metadata and properties
        //cloudFile.Metadata
        //cloudFile.Properties
    }
    else if (item is CloudFileDirectory)
    {
        var cloudFileDirectory = (CloudFileDirectory)item;
        // You can now access metadata and properties
        //cloudFileDirectory.Metadata
        //cloudFileDirectory.Properties
    }
}
```

Comment: The properties are still not populated,  It seems that I need to tell the request that I want them but I don't see that options.  I hope the CloudFile properties are not just set when fetching the file.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Thomas's post...  This is the only way I have found.

```
foreach (var item in results)
{
    if (item is CloudFile)
    {
        var cloudFile = (CloudFile) item;
        cloudFile.FetchAttributes();

        // You can now access metadata and properties
        //cloudFile.Metadata
        //cloudFile.Properties
    }
    else if (item is CloudFileDirectory)
    {
        var cloudFileDirectory = (CloudFileDirectory)item;
        // You can now access metadata and properties
        //cloudFileDirectory.Metadata
        //cloudFileDirectory.Properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately listing does not return properties/metadata for files. This is the correct solution.